# Share scripts between Angular apps

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Good morning, 
I'm trying to write two different Angular2 apps that share the same business logic but are different in layout, style and animations.

What i would do with a "classic" html + css + js website would be to create my custom html + css + js and reference the common ones. 
The advantage of this solution is the possibility to fix bugs or modify the shared code easily.

So for example in web website structure like this one :

```
└─┬www
    |
    ├─┬WebSite1 
    | └ site1.html
    | └ style1.css
    | └ script1.js
    ├─┬WebSite2
    | └ site2.html
    | └ style2.css
    | └ script2.js
    ├─┬Shared 
    | └ shared.js
```

I can reference "shared.js" from website1 and website2.

With Angular i understand that i have build two different applications, maybe sharing "library" code, but if I have to modify some shared code I have to rebuild the two applications.

Am I correct ? Do you have any good suggestion to deploy two application in an easier way ?

Comment: create a shared "feature" module and deploy it as a versioned package to npm. Then each website can install the shared library easily: npm install <package>

Comment: Hi pixelbits, thank you for your answer ! With this solution if i modify my package i need to rebuild both the websites and deploy them again, this is my concern. Am I correct ?

Comment: That is correct. Your package is versioned on npm. If you want to deploy your website with the updated version of your package, you need to re-build it.  sure np. check out this starter-app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-starter-app. It demonstrates how to build and package a module.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to organize an Angular project, most notably by-feature (i.e. product feature) and by-file-type (i.e. different directory for html, different directory for services, less files etc.)
In your case what suits the best is by-file-type, so you can just include the business-logic module, which may contain relevant `services`, from any other instances of angular application that require this logic.